# Change installer intro image

Tags: install4j

Is there any way to modify the image on the left-side of the first screen of an installer generated with Install4J?

So far the only branding I've been able to do is modify the "header" image displayed in the upper right-hand side corner.

The image I'm referring to is the following.

[image: modify_vertical_banner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Welcome screen (and other similar screens) have an "Image for banner" property where you can specify your own image.